# search sql server schema on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ODP.Net with oracle and MVC ASP.NET.

I don't know why it is searching sql server schema. i am using oracle .Net Driver ODP.Net

what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the schema name with fluent mappings and remove the `Table` data annotation (I don't think data annotation supports specifying the schema)...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("DEPARTMENT", "HR");

}
```